# curl: (26) couldn't open file when getting command arguments from a string

Tags: shell, curl

I'm trying to build a function that returns arguments for curl:

```
get_common_curl_headers() {
  local crash_path="$1"

  echo -n \
    "-H 'Accept: text/plain'" \
    "-F 'model=<$crash_path/model'" \
    "-F 'version=<$crash_path/fw_version'"

  echo -n ' '
}
```

I'd like the returned file paths to be quoted as `$crash_path` variable might contain spaces. I then use this function like this:

```
send_app_crash() {
  local crash_path="$1"
  local common_headers

  common_headers=$(get_common_curl_headers "$crash_path")
  [ $? -ne 0 ] && return 1

  curl -vk -X POST \
    $common_headers\
    "$SERVER_URL"
}
```

I use the variable `$common_headers` unquoted here, as I want the arguments to be expanded, which to my understanding should work. However, the command results in this error:

```
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'text'
curl: (26) couldn't open file "/tmp//model'"
```

Weirdly, there's an extra single quote at the end of the file name, which should have been removed by the shell. I'm not sure what the first error means as well, as `Accept: text/plain` seems to be properly quoted (see below).

Running the command manually (i.e. doing `set -x` before the command appears inside the script and piping it to `sh`) works as intended:

```
curl -vk -X POST -H 'Accept: text/plain' -F 'model=</tmp//model' -F 'version=</tmp//fw_version' 192.168.2.100:8888
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### How to debug

By just adding `set -x` before your curl command, you'd see this:

```
curl -vk -X POST -H ''\''Accept:' 'text/plain'\''' -F ''\''model=<some-crash-path/model'\''' -F ''\''version=<some-crash-path/fw_version'\''' example.com
```

And now let's do some magic trick:

```
$ printf "%s\n" curl -vk -X POST -H ''\''Accept:' 'text/plain'\''' -F ''\''model=<some-crash-path/model'\''' -F ''\''version=<some-crash-path/fw_version'\''' example.com
curl
-vk
-X
POST
-H
'Accept:
text/plain'
-F
'model=<some-crash-path/model'
-F
'version=<some-crash-path/fw_version'
example.com
```

This `printf` command prints every argument in a separate line, which can help you see that instead of e.g. `Accept: test/plain`, you generated 2 arguments: `'Accept:` and `text/plain'`.

So curl sees it as `-H 'Accept:` (i.e. the header starts with `'` and does not include the intended value), and the next argument is `text/plain'`, which is not prefixed by any option, so curl thinks it's the URL, which is why it says `text` is not a host.

It also explains why it can't find `/tmp/model'` (with `'` at the end).

### How to fix

Instead of using

```
curl -vk -X POST $common_headers "$SERVER_URL"
```

Just add `eval`:

```
eval curl -vk -X POST $common_headers "$SERVER_URL"
```

For your purposes, `eval` is equivalent to piping to `sh`.

### The right way

I would generally advise against using `eval` (or piping to `sh`) for anything but throw-away code.

How would you do it otherwise?

Option 1 - inline `get_common_curl_headers()` inside `send_app_crash()`. That's what I prefer to do - introduce functions which wrap commands rather than generating arguments in a separate function.

```
send_app_crash() {
    local crash_path="$1"
    curl -vk \
        -X POST \
        -H "Accept: text/plain" \
        -F "model=<$crash_path/model" \
        -F "version=<$crash_path/fw_version" \
        "$SERVER_URL"
}
```

Option 2 - Generate the arguments in a global array:

```
get_common_curl_headers() {
    local crash_path="$1"

    COMMON_HEADERS=( \
        -H "Accept: text/plain" \
        -F "model=<$crash_path/model" \
        -F "version=<$crash_path/fw_version" \
    )
}

send_app_crash() {
    local crash_path="$1"
    local common_headers

    get_common_curl_headers "$crash_path"
    [ $? -ne 0 ] && return 1

    curl -vk -X POST "${COMMON_HEADERS[@]}" "$SERVER_URL"
}
```

Note the quoting of the array dereference, and note that you can't return arrays.

The main problem with this approach is that it uses global variables, which is why it's less preferable.